# Store JS var into database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a script which increments certain variable every time the script runs. I want the data to be saved into my database when the page refreshes. However I don't know how to save this JS variable into my database since it's not a php variable.

HTML

```
<td id="cash"><?php echo $cash; ?></td>
```

JS

```
setInterval(function() {
var $cash = $('#cash');
$cash.text(parseInt($cash.text())+75);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If it is literally a single data point that you want to store, and keep updating, then it's probably easier for you to use a text file on the server and `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`.  If you choose to go database/table route, here is a tutorial to get started: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: Why do you need to store the value? What are you going to use it for? (Depending on what you need it for could change the proper answer to your question. You might not need a database at all for example).

Comment: easiest way is to use ajax to send the the data to a PHP script file -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ -- search for (Save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete.) -- Php mysql insert -- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: I´m already using a database were I get the $cash value from. This $cash variable gets higher every second. Now I need to update the new value to the database when I switch or refresh pages.

Comment: Modify your question to say you want to Update a record in your database  -- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Answer (score 1):

Solution : Ajax

You will need to send it to server side.
jquery make it much easier

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for something like this.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript worked in your browser. Database placed on the server

You need listen changes in element with id cash. If it changes — send AJAX request with information about new value to your server and update database on the server.